# GIT change list creation issue when feature branches merge into develop

Tags: git, jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline

Our branching strategy is as mentioned below:

We have develop branch and we create feature branches(feature/example) out of it. We may work on feature branches for a month or two months and again merge it back into develop. Before Merging back into develop we keep merging develop into feature branch to keep the code updated.

Issue is :-

1. feature/example branch is created from branch develop.
2. modified few files in develop branch and added commit A, commit b and commit c to develop.
3. Triggered jenkins build and commit A, Commit B and Commit C are being shown in change list file for build no. 1.
4. Develop branch is merged into feature/example and commit A, commit b and commit c are added into feature/example.
5. Now few files are modified in feature/example and commit D, commit E, commit F are added to it.
6. Now development on feature/example branch is completed and I merged it into develop.
7. I triggered a jenkins build for develop branch to build the newly merged changes and in change list file I can see commit A, commit b, commit c, commit d , commit e and commit f in build 2.

My question is how to avoid change list from displaying commit A, commit b and commit c as all these commits already went through previous build.

Comment: How is this changelist generated ? Where does it appear ?

Comment: Can you create a timeline of events here? With items such as "create branch" "commit X on branch Y", "push", "pull" and "merge"?

Comment: LeGEC - Change list is generated through jenkins pipeline script.

Comment: Lasse- Updated timeline

Comment: The changelist that Jenkins generates is useless and you should simply ignore it. If you need a meaningful changelist you should generate it yourself.

Comment: MaratC - But I want to know the newly introduced chages in every build through Jenkins